# Creating a function in Coldfusion to dynamically convert a multidimensional array to a query object

Tags: multidimensional-array, coldfusion

The problem I'm running into is the API I'm using for this particular project uses periods in the keys which is not allowed in query column names. So I need to figure out a way to rename the array keys to remove the periods (or replace them with an underscore). Here is the code I have so far, which is working, but throws an error when hitting the "accumulator.addRow" line. The error being that periods aren't allowed in column names.

```
<cfset varResults = '[{"roW_NUMBER":1,"membership.Individual.LocalID":999,"membership.Individual.FirstName":"AA","membership.Individual.LastName":"AA","membership.Individual.Company":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line1":"aaaa","membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line2":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_City":"Alexandria","membership.Individual.Work_Address_State":"VA","membership.Individual.Work_Address_PostalCode":"9999-2518","membership.Individual.Work_Address_CountryName":"UNITED STATES","membership.Individual.EmailAddress":"AA.AA@gmail.com","membership.Type.Name":"Regular","membership.JoinDate":"2009-05-01T00:00:00","membership.ExpirationDate":"2023-04-30T00:00:00","membership.Individual.FellowElectDate__c":null,"chapter.Name":"DDDD","id":"0e04bc98-0074-cc58-bf6a-0b438d800e7d"},{"roW_NUMBER":2,"membership.Individual.LocalID":9998,"membership.Individual.FirstName":"AA","membership.Individual.LastName":"AA","membership.Individual.Company":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line1":"ASASASAAASAS","membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line2":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_City":"Washington","membership.Individual.Work_Address_State":"DC","membership.Individual.Work_Address_PostalCode":"9999","membership.Individual.Work_Address_CountryName":"UNITED STATES","membership.Individual.EmailAddress":"ASASASA@gmail.com","membership.Type.Name":"Regular","membership.JoinDate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00","membership.ExpirationDate":"2022-12-31T00:00:00","membership.Individual.FellowElectDate__c":null,"chapter.Name":"DDDD","id":"0e04bc98-0074-c1ae-f171-0b438d800e7c"}]'>
```

```
<cfscript>
    function arrayToQuery(varChapterRoster) {
        return varChapterRoster.reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
            element.each(function(key) {
                if (!accumulator.keyExists(replace(key,".","_","all"))) {
                    accumulator.addColumn(replace(key,".","_","all"), []);
                }
            });
            //writeDump(element);
            accumulator.addRow(element);
            return accumulator;
        }, QueryNew(""));
    }
    // writeDump(varChapterRoster);
    writeDump(arrayToQuery(varChapterRoster));
</cfscript>
```

Specific error: Column names must be valid variable names. They must start with a letter and can only include letters, numbers, and underscores.

I got past the "keyexists" and "addcolumn" lines by using the replace function, but replace won't work on "element" (throws an error) on the addRow line.

Changing tactics, here is a [CFFiddle](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=5cb59596-cc2c-4e18-bc85-334d4a2228d8/2d9d6041-dbe8-4a99-80d4-6bfbfe078d8e/22d7aed8-d5ff-425a-87d8-358bc7b4acd3.cfm) with some dummy data in it of the method I'm trying now. I think it is more straight forward, but getting another error that I bet is related to the periods again.

Comment: Is accumulator a query or a struct? Can you use .keyExists() on a query? I know you can use it on a struct.

Comment: Can you show us a JSON representation of the array?  Or at least a modified version with the values redacted if sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfset varResults = '[{"roW_NUMBER":1,"membership.Individual.LocalID":999,"membership.Individual.FirstName":"AA","membership.Individual.LastName":"AA","membership.Individual.Company":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line1":"aaaa","membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line2":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_City":"Alexandria","membership.Individual.Work_Address_State":"VA","membership.Individual.Work_Address_PostalCode":"9999-2518","membership.Individual.Work_Address_CountryName":"UNITED STATES","membership.Individual.EmailAddress":"AA.AA@gmail.com","membership.Type.Name":"Regular","membership.JoinDate":"2009-05-01T00:00:00","membership.ExpirationDate":"2023-04-30T00:00:00","membership.Individual.FellowElectDate__c":null,"chapter.Name":"DDDD","id":"0e04bc98-0074-cc58-bf6a-0b438d800e7d"},{"roW_NUMBER":2,"membership.Individual.LocalID":9998,"membership.Individual.FirstName":"AA","membership.Individual.LastName":"AA","membership.Individual.Company":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line1":"ASASASAAASAS","membership.Individual.Work_Address_Line2":null,"membership.Individual.Work_Address_City":"Washington","membership.Individual.Work_Address_State":"DC","membership.Individual.Work_Address_PostalCode":"9999","membership.Individual.Work_Address_CountryName":"UNITED STATES","membership.Individual.EmailAddress":"ASASASA@gmail.com","membership.Type.Name":"Regular","membership.JoinDate":"2020-01-01T00:00:00","membership.ExpirationDate":"2022-12-31T00:00:00","membership.Individual.FellowElectDate__c":null,"chapter.Name":"DDDD","id":"0e04bc98-0074-c1ae-f171-0b438d800e7c"}]'>
<cfset varResults = replace(varResults,":null",':""',"All")>
<cfset varResults = replace(varResults,"T00:00:00","","All")>
<cfset varResults = deserializeJSON(varResults)>
```

Answer based on original post. [Demo](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=98ceda61-a7ef-4cbf-8f34-e0bf26ad896f/6445a953-ab8f-4119-8dfc-a839bb7b504b/56190ec6-c47c-4388-a843-971dfed6339e.cfm)

```
<cfscript>
    function arrayToQuery(varChapterRoster) {
        if(varChapterRoster.len() == 0){
            return QueryNew('');
        }
        return varChapterRoster.reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
            Row = QueryAddRow(accumulator);
            element.each(function(key) {
                QuerySetCell( accumulator , replace(key,".","_","all") , element[key] , Row );
            });
            return accumulator;
        }, QueryNew(replace(StructKeyList(varResults[1]),".","_","all")));
    }
    // writeDump(varChapterRoster);
    writeDump(arrayToQuery(varResults));
</cfscript>
```

Answer based on your cffiddle. [Demo](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=d30d8547-7a56-4424-bc9b-dd87ae86e8a2/3facbd6b-8bca-48c2-b939-7f50d85447c6/46b95a59-805c-4368-9c7a-92ba09de303d.cfm)

```
<cfif NOT ArrayLen(varResults)>
    <cfthrow message="No data" />
</cfif>

<cfset Q = QueryNew( replace(StructKeyList(varResults[1]),".","_","all") ) />

<cfloop index="item" array="#varResults#">
    <cfset Row = QueryAddRow(Q) />
    <cfloop item="ColName" collection="#item#" >
        <cfset QuerySetCell( Q , replace(ColName,".","_","all") , item[ColName] , Row ) />
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var=#Q# />
```